# Sticky footer CSS - Why does compass' mixin use an empty div?

Tags: css, compass-sass

Looking at [compass' sticky footer mixin example](http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/layout/sticky-footer/) they use an extra (empty) div in `#layout` with the same height as the actual footer to keep the layout correctly.

Why don't they instead remove that div, and add `box-sizing` and `padding-bottom` to `#layout`? From what I can see it has the same effect: http://jsfiddle.net/b3P5H/

Comment: box-sizing is partially supported in browsers  http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing

Comment: "Partial support refers to supporting only the "border-box" value, not "padding-box" (which was added to the spec later)." My implmentation only needs `border-box`

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12253099/497418), although I will eventually need to update that answer with the way to build a sticky footer in flexbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they didn't realize there was a better way and were probably just implementing [Ryan Fait's sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/).