# Footer not staying at the bottom in Firefox

Tags: html, css

So I have a footer that stays at the bottom but isn't fixed, however it doesn't work in Firefox only.

```css
.Links {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #E48A4B;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<footer>
  <div class="Links">
    <a href="https://codepen.io/mexO/">
      <i class="fa fa-codepen fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>

    </a>
    <a href="https://jsfiddle.net/user/mexO/fiddles/">
      <i class="fa fa-jsfiddle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/MaxJordanNet">
      <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="https://github.com/mexOcode">
      <i class="fa fa-github fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="updates.html">
      <i class="updatesButton fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>


  </div>
</footer>
```

Now it works if i change absolute to fixed in the CSS however that make it always on the page, which isn't what i want. It works in all other browsers i have tested apart from FireFox.

Also i have already tried using the only solution i could find, *clear: both;* but that didn't work either.

EDIT: My poor wording is confusing people.

Go to maxjordan.net on chrome to see for youself, but i want it to look like this

https://gyazo.com/b81099b69c43367769a46b321b327440
(Ignore the broken footer on the home page, just know thats the position i want it.)

However on firefox it looks like this:

https://gyazo.com/58a4e7a24a8e365aba2918d2aa4c8525

Comment: This works fine in firefox http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNzYzb please include all of your code and a replicable example of the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: try making the footer postiong relative by putting this style on the footer- <footer style="postion:relative">

Comment: Source code can be found at maxjordan.net

Comment: Also using style="postion:relative" doesnt work.

Comment: Do not just point people to source code on another website. It's fine to include a link but post your code here. If the source code on the link changes, your question becomes obsolete.

Comment: Theres like 4k lines of source code, im not sure how i would post it all.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I believe what you're looking for is here:

[Footer at bottom of page or content, whichever is lower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239166/footer-at-bottom-of-page-or-content-whichever-is-lower)

If you want the footer to keep pinned to the bottom - even with content scrolling - change the `position` from `absolute` to `fixed`.

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/iamjpg/rz2ddzx6/

```
.Links {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #E48A4B;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Thats what i dont want thought, i want it to be at the bottom of the page, even if the content doesnt fill the page.

Comment: I'm guessing that what you want is it to be at the bottom unless the content exceeds the window?

Comment: I want it to be at the bottom, all the time.

Comment: Go to maxjordan.net

I want it to be like that (On chrome) but if you try it on firefox it doesnt work.

Comment: Check this other stackoverflow awnser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239166/footer-at-bottom-of-page-or-content-whichever-is-lower

Comment: this is a sticky footer, what about letting footer be at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Keep the position fixed instead of absolute.

Answer (score 0):

remove position absolute and just put footer tag bottom, in the end of html