# Footer needs to be bottom of the page and also below all the elements

Tags: html, css

I made a footer element sticked to the bottom of the page. but, if there is excess elements present in the container. footer element overlaps the container. [fiddle link attached here](https://jsfiddle.net/emkx5wLq/1/)

```html
<div>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        .....
</div>
<footer>
    <h1>Footer Content</h1>
</footer>
```

Here i have bunch of `<p>` tags, but `footer` element overlaps few of the `p` element.

I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: Change your footer from `absolute` to `relative`

Comment: if i am using `position: relative` to footer. then the footer is not sticked to the bottom of the page. now i removed most of the `<p>` tags. https://jsfiddle.net/emkx5wLq/2/

Comment: @DylanAnlezark please check the above fiddle. it should wok in all the cases.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this problem and worked for me right now it is by using `flex` with direction `column` and set the footer child `align-self: end`. Like this, you will guarantee nothing will overlap nothing.

Check this stack question [Footer at bottom of page or content, whichever is lower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239166/footer-at-bottom-of-page-or-content-whichever-is-lower). It will help you understand more.

```css
*,
*:before, 
*:after{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body{
   height: 100%;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
   min-height: 100%;
}

.hello-wrapper{
  padding: 2rem 3rem;
}

footer{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #444;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  aligh-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
<div class="hello-wrapper">
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        <p>Helloworld</p>
        
    </div>
<footer>
    <h1>Footer Content</h1>
</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: let me check this @DINA TAKLIT

Comment: I will add a new approach that I am trying now and looks that is working. Let me just checking it is a correction of my first answer.

Comment: It still not working when it has fewer <P> tags. i just tried your solution, pls check the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/ju9wmky2/

Comment: footer is not coming to bottom of the page.

Comment: I have added a min-height to solve the issuer of few paragraph in the link I have added you will find many versions of solutions

Comment: the codepen link you shared working in many cases. thanks.

Comment: THe flew box answer works if we add min-height for the wrapper in case of lower elements. For the other answers for absolute elements you can check the link I shared in the answer it is very useful.