# Sticky footer doesn't work on angular application using a flex layout technique

Tags: css, flexbox, angular13

I can't make the footer stick to the end of the page when the main "content" is not enough to put it at the bottom.

[image]

My dom is like this.

[image]

My CSS is like this.

```
  body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

html {
  height:100%;
}

main {

  flex: 1 0 auto;
    
}

footer {
  background-color:red;
}


  


  .error {

    border: 1px solid red;

  }

  a {
      color:blue;
      text-decoration: none;
  }
```

Comment: The footer is not directly in the body, but in your `<app-root>`. The `app-root` needs to have a 100% height as well. (Try setting its height to `100vw` and look if it makes a difference. The `display: flex` needs to go on the `app-root` as well of course.) Here is an example with live demo: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12239166/6336728